# cakephp 3 paginator sorting on computed associated data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have some deep association and I need to paginate/sort upon some aggregation function results on those deep associations.

For example: 
Entity A hasMany B; B hasMany C
In entity A index page I need to show count of C and use it in pagination/sorting.

Then again A hasMany D and I need to show group_concat of a column from D

Another one: Entity A belongs to E and I need to show number of A entities with a column (lets say id for sake of simplicity) lower than the current one but only from those that belong to E). Practical example - I have a packet (entity E) of candy (entity A), I take out first candy from the packet so it will have a number of 0, I took out second candy and it has number 1 and so on.
But candy from different packet will have its own numeric line.

I know, how to write custom query to achieve that, but how can I do this with Cake's paginator?

Comment: Please include your SQL solution.